# Best practices for users credentials

Tags: mysql, best-practices, access-control, logging

I am designing a C# client to connect to a MySQL DB and am having second thoughts on my design.

The users have credentials in order login in the C# client, so now it is designed like this:
1 - the C# client has its own username/password to connect to the DB.
2 - the DB has a table "Users" that holds names, passwords and access level.
3 - when the user logs in, what happens is the client logs in the DB using its standard user/pass and queries the "Users" table to check if user's credentials match.

So for the DB it is always the same user that connects to it.

But now I need to log activities such as update/delete/insert, linking them to the user responsible.

The question is:
- what are the benefits and drawbacks of my current design compared to each user having actual DB credentials and the C# client using them to connect?

Comment: welcome to DBA Stack Exchange. Unfortunately I am voting to close your question. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. thank you.

Comment: Removed second question

Comment: there are probably twice as many opinions on this subject as there are people willing to share them, so choose what _you_ think is best, for _your_ definition of "best".

Comment: Is "access level" a purely SQL permission level construct? What MySQL version (sometimes there's specific features that can help)? Do you trust the integrity of your users/C# application or are you after the database to be the barrier? Do you have to use user/password or is there an already existing user-wide authentication?

Comment: @danblack MySQL Server 8.0.19.0. Currently the client is running only inside the LAN and I trust its integrity, but in the future there are plans to also have the access from a web application.